# Non-linear Gradients

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, gradient

I saw this graphic the other day and wondered, how I'd the gradient done?

It looks like a linear gradient but instead of going left to right it starts at the base of the wing and curves up to the tip as if it follows the path of the actual wing. How is this done? (Photoshop or illustrator by the way)

[image: Multiple Non-Linear Gradients]

Comment: Seems to me the image uses radial gradients. But yes you can do any shape gradients with fradient mesh

Answer (score 2):

There are needed nothing special. Different gradients - radial and linear, two stop and three stop - in different shapes and probably outer glow around white eagle's head.

Unfortunately I cant draw respectable eagle's head to prove this, but hopefully these fishes are believable enough

[image]